# Privacy Indicator Green dot control flow

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

From Android S OS we can see [Privacy Indicators](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/privacy-indicators#:%7E:text=Runtime%20permissions%20in%20Android%206,a%20dialog%20the%20system%20presents.) . When any of the sensors like Microphone, Camera or Location is being used by any of the app then this Green dot is visible in the Status bar just like Battery Icon. And this is visible even after screen goes off(also in lock screen).

- Q1> Is this Green dot is a sensor light or is it a Image view with tint color
- Q2> Is this possible to back port this feature to older Android version

Can anyone give me the pointer to the implementation part of creating this Green dot in AOSP code base (CSAndroid). Any input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From SystemUI point of view Privacy dot view is created in [frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/events/PrivacyDotViewController.kt](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/events/PrivacyDotViewController.kt;l=65?q=PrivacyDotViewController&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject:frameworks%2Fbase%2Fpackages%2FSystemUI%2F)  view  class.

When the device is rotated from Portrait to Landscape mode (both clockwise and anti clock wise) then the green dot is also moved along with battery icon and showed top right corner for each rotation. So it showed in three different places when the screen rotates to Portrait , clock wise and anti clock wise land scape rotation.

Hence it is not a hardware sensor light. It is a Status bar Icon which is showing [showDotView](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/events/PrivacyDotViewController.kt;l=181?q=PrivacyDot&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) and [hideDotView](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/events/PrivacyDotViewController.kt;l=166?q=PrivacyDot&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) from PrivacyDotViewController.kt class.